# SDImageCache unable to retrieve the saved images in Cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage to store the images in cache and disk memory using a key but while querying using that key i am not getting the images, the code is

```
 SDImageCache *imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] initWithNamespace:@"ImageCacheFolder"];
[imageCache queryCacheOperationForKey:[entryidarray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] done:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    if (image) {
        NSLog(@"image get from cache");
        [imageview setImage:image];
    } else {
        [imageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceholderImage-Day"] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload];
    } 
}];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgStr];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

if (img) {
    NSLog(@"the image is not nil");
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:img forKey:[entryidarray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] toDisk:YES completion:nil];
}else {
    NSLog(@"the image is nil");
}
```

Comment: by default `SDImageCache` used the cache policy then why you need additional cache

Comment: one feature was there for that i need to get the image using key thats why i am trying like.

Comment: ok then why you used two threads

Comment: due to that only it didn't worked, now i am using one thread only and its working fine. thanks for notifying me that error bro :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
.

```
if (img) {
    NSLog(@"the image is not nil");
    [imageCache storeImage:img forKey:[entryidarray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] toDisk:YES completion:nil];
}else {
    NSLog(@"the image is nil");
}
```